# Change of basis in linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why do we go for change of Basis ? And where is it used in real time application ?

What is the differenc between change of basis and transformation?

Comment: Consider linear transformations acting on a vector space $V$. Then, a change of basis is invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

A change of basis is very useful because you can use it to write a matrix in diagonal form which makes it much easier to compute powers of the matrix.

Some but not all linear transformations from a vector space to itself are equivalent to changing the basis.  (In particular, the linear transformation must be invertible.)